# PySimpleGUI | Whats the difference between window() and window.read()?

Tags: pysimplegui

I was coding a gui from memory and accidentally used the following line in my event loop:

```
event, value = window()
```

The proper way is shown as:

```
event, value = window.read()
```

Calling print on each one returns the same thing:

```
window()=('OK', {0: 'asd'})
window.read()=('OK', {0: 'asd'})
```

**Is there a difference?**
My gui worked perfectly fine. I tried a couple of different tests to break it or figure out what the difference was and couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both of them are the same.

```py
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Call window.read but without having to type it out.
        window() == window.read()
        window(timeout=50) == window.read(timeout=50)

        :return: The famous event, values that read returns.
        :rtype:  Tuple[Any, Dict[Any, Any]]
        """
        return self.read(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the purpose of .read()? It seems like the PySimpleGUI guys are all about minimizing the amount of code you need to write. So I feel like there has to be a purpose for it. (Readability?) I will leave the question up for a bit and if I get no other responses I will mark your answer correct.

Comment: IMO, method `read` handle to job to finalize or refresh the GUI, also the event handler to get `event, values` back if any event happened, and else.

Comment: Use `read`.  It's explicit (I like explicit/clear more than simple) and enables searching through code to find the places a window is read.  It was an experiment... and one I kinda wish I hadn't added.  But, it was released and since it's in use, don't want to break anyone's code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference.
You call `window()` to display it but I would advise to do the following:

```
import PySimpleGUI as Sg
WINDOW = Sg.Window("new stuff",
                   some_layout_defined_in_PySimpleGUI,
                   icon=UI_ICON,
                   finalize=True,
                   font=FONT_NORMAL)
```

Now you have your window. You then start a `while True` loop and at first:

```
while True:
    event, values = WINDOW.read(timeout=1)
```

Both should work but based on this https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5400 it is better to rely on WINDOW.read().

Comment: I actually found that github issue in my search before posting the question. I didn't really see how it related to my question. Maybe I am missing something? Is there an example of it breaking something or why exactly it is bad? Just curious / want to understand why we use .read() exactly.

Comment: It's not "bad". It's not recommended by the project. It's not standard. It's not normal. You don't normally "call" an object in Python.  You call some method that object has. Leaving off the `read` method name results in ambiguous code.  You don't know exactly what's happening by looking at the line of code making the call.